# Question on Precision and Recall

Tags: machine-learning, model-evaluation, overfitting, precision-recall, pattern-recognition

Is it possible to have both Precision and Recall to be equal to 1.

If such a case may exist, does it mean the system is over-fitting the dataset?

Comment: Yes it is possible. Yes, because it means the answer was perfect. No, this is not good, it means your evaluation method is flawed.

Comment: How can it be overfitting? Doesn't overfitting mean high training accuracy and low test accuracy? I don't seem to have that problem?

Comment: Any evaluation methodology you use that allows you to get a perfect result must be busted... there is no perfect system, ever. Because there is no perfect data in reality, either!
I consider any result that is close to 1.0 to be fake.

Comment: It could be that you have a dataset with easily separable classes.  This doesn't happen much in practice but could happen with a toy or small dataset. The dataset might also have problems like leakage between the classes and predictor variables (e.g., patients are compared to historic controls and date-of-first-visit is accidentally included as a predictor). Either way I agree with @Anony-Mousse that you should worry. A related interesting problem is how do you estimate confidence intervals?  Obuchowski and Lieber (2002) address this w ROC simulations but only use small N.

Comment: One can get perfect performance on mouse vs. elephant classification from weight. It's not a problem anyone really uses ML on, but some real-life problems are like that. On the other hand, in many real-life applications such as medical predictions (e.g. will this patient die within 1 y, does this patient have diagnosis X etc.), perfect performance is extremely unlikely (even values in the 0.85 to 1.0 range are suspicious) & points to the possibility of a problem with the evaluation set-up. Of course, another possibility is that there's very few test cases, in which case on can get "lucky".

Answer (score 0):

If recall is $1$, then the model is catching all of the positive cases. $P(\hat y=1\vert y=1)=1$.

If precision is $1$, then the model is only catching cases of the positive category that actually belong yo the positive category. $P(y=1\vert \hat y=1)=1$.

If both of these equal one, then your model is catching all of the positive cases without classifying a negative case as positive. This mean that all positive and negative cases are classified correctly: $100\%$ accuracy.

Perfect accuracy is an extremely high standard that might be possible on easy data, but this suggests overfitting to me. Such performance is just a little bit too good. Even MNIST classifiers make the occasional mistake.